# Handling browsers which do not meet my transpile target

Tags: typescript, browser, babeljs, user-agent, esbuild

Using Babel, TypeScript esbuild, and others, we are able to target our transpiled code to the features of a particular family of browsers. We can specify a range of browsers based on various criteria (> 0.5%, last 2 versions, Firefox ESR, not dead) or we can indicate a particular version of the ES spec (ES2018) and the transpiled code will be generated to be compliant with the browsers that support the features defined in those groups.

But what about the "minimum system requirements" page we need to use to send users whom are using a browser older that the browsers within our target group?

Browserslist has a list of [libraries for showing unsupported browsers](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#show-we-do-not-support-your-browser-banner), but they are old and rely on user agent string.

Are there better tools/libraries/approaches to address this problem in 2022?